# select_by_visible_text python selenium ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to programmatically select a currency in the site: http://www.asos.com/asos/asos-skinny-chinos-in-dark-khaki/prd/5542109

However it's doing some problems to me, I am using this following piece of code:

```
def set_currency(text):
    one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
    one.click()
    select_element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
    select = Select(select_element)
    select.select_by_visible_text(text)
```

Sometimes it gives me this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException:` in this line `select.select_by_visible_text(text)` but sometimes it works just fine. I am using `WebDriverWait` until it is visible so I can't understand why it
s doing this errors.

Full error if needed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 35, in <module>
    set_currency(currency)
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 18, in set_currency
    select.select_by_visible_text(text)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 120, in select_by_visible_text
    self._setSelected(opt)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 212, in _setSelected
    option.click()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:17758","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1479563250968\", \"sessionId\": \"b2aa4180-ae5e-11e6-b8b3-e1a4ad040bb7\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/b2aa4180-ae5e-11e6-b8b3-e1a4ad040bb7/element/:wdc:1479563250968/click"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

**Edit:**

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
import traceback
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver1 = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'C:\Users\dodob\Desktop\Apps Workspace\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')

def set_currency(label):
    is_change_currency_displayed = driver1.find_element_by_id("currencyList").is_displayed()
    if not is_change_currency_displayed:
        print("dropdown is not displayed.")
        one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
        one.click()
    select_element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
    select = Select(select_element)
    select.select_by_visible_text(label)


def get_all_currencies():
    one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
    one.click()
    el = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
    currency2 = []
    options = el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    for option in options:
        currency2.append(option.text)
    return currency2


def main(url):
    print(url)
    driver1.get(url)
    to_return_string = ''
    list_of_currencies = get_all_currencies()
    print(list_of_currencies)
    for currency in list_of_currencies:
        try:
            set_currency(currency)
            current_price = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".current-price")))
            to_return_string += ("In " + currency + " : " + current_price.text + ' \n')
            print("In", currency, ":", current_price.text)
        except TimeoutException:
            print(traceback.print_exc())
            print("In", currency, ":", "Timed out waiting for page to load")
            to_return_string += ("In " + currency + " : " + " Timed out waiting for page to load" + ' \n')
        except ElementNotVisibleException:
            print(traceback.print_exc())
    return to_return_string


main('http://www.asos.com/it/asos/asos-jeans-skinny-alla-caviglia-kaki/prd/6759361')
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
C:\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py
http://www.asos.com/it/asos/asos-jeans-skinny-alla-caviglia-kaki/prd/6759361
['£ GBP', '$ USD', 'C$ CAD', 'kr SEK', 'kr NOK', 'kr DKK', '₣ CHF', ' € EUR', '$ AUD', '¥ RMB', '$ HKD', '$ NZD', '$ SGD', 'NT$ TWD', 'руб.  RUB']
In £ GBP : € 33,99
In $ USD : € 33,99
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
In C$ CAD : Timed out waiting for page to load
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 43, in main
    set_currency(currency)
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 19, in set_currency
    select_element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

dropdown is not displayed.
In kr SEK : € 33,99
In kr NOK : € 33,99
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 43, in main
    set_currency(currency)
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 21, in set_currency
    select.select_by_visible_text(label)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 120, in select_by_visible_text
    self._setSelected(opt)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 212, in _setSelected
    option.click()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:60873","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1479841552848\", \"sessionId\": \"aae52750-b0e6-11e6-a0c1-5193111f996c\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/aae52750-b0e6-11e6-a0c1-5193111f996c/element/:wdc:1479841552848/click"}}
Screenshot: available via screen

dropdown is not displayed.
In ₣ CHF : € 33,99
In  € EUR : € 33,99
Traceback (most recent call last):
None
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 43, in main
    set_currency(currency)
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 21, in set_currency
    select.select_by_visible_text(label)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 120, in select_by_visible_text
    self._setSelected(opt)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 212, in _setSelected
    option.click()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:60873","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1479841552851\", \"sessionId\": \"aae52750-b0e6-11e6-a0c1-5193111f996c\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/aae52750-b0e6-11e6-a0c1-5193111f996c/element/:wdc:1479841552851/click"}}
Screenshot: available via screen

dropdown is not displayed.
In ¥ RMB : € 33,99
In $ HKD : € 33,99
None
In $ NZD : Timed out waiting for page to load
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 43, in main
    set_currency(currency)
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 19, in set_currency
    select_element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

dropdown is not displayed.
In $ SGD : € 33,99
In NT$ TWD : € 33,99
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
In руб.  RUB : Timed out waiting for page to load
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 43, in main
    set_currency(currency)
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 19, in set_currency
    select_element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: generally this error occur when you have overlap element and your element is not visible

Comment: @thebadguy It doesn't help me much... :/

Comment: Sounds like a race condition.  Explicit waits, only wait until the element is visible, once the element is visible it continues on with the next line in the sequence of code.  Sounds like you may need a implicit or just a sleep in between the explicit and the action.  I recommend this only because it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: In select.select_by_visible_text(text) - what are the values text can become?

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein You can see the get_all_currencies function, anyway, ['£ GBP', '$ USD', 'C$ CAD', 'kr SEK', 'kr NOK', 'kr DKK', '₣ CHF', ' € EUR', '$ AUD', '¥ RMB', '$ HKD', '$ NZD', '$ SGD', 'NT$ TWD', 'руб.  RUB']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

Code seems to be fine. But it is the order in which the calls are made are causing the issue.

When the following line is called in `main` method:

```
list_of_currencies = get_all_currencies()
```

you are clicking on `selected-currency` in the following line of get_all_currencies() method:

```
one.click() // opens the "Change-Currency" dropdown menu as shown in below image
```

and no further action taken in the method.

then we call `set_currency(currency)` in `for loop of main method`.

in the `set_currency(currency)` method again we are clicking on `selected-currency`, which is actually closing the opened dropdown of `Change-Currency`, which results in Element Not Visible Exception.

**Solution:**

So, change the flow to make sure that `Change-Currency` dropdown is opened before you call `set_by_visible_text` method.

Check whether the `Change-Currency` dropdown is already opened using `isDisplayed` method.

Following is the code: (added 2 new lines in the beginning)

```
def set_currency(label):
    isChangeCurrencyDisplayed  = driver.find_element_by_id("currencyList").is_displayed()
    if not isChangeCurrencyDisplayed:
        print "dropdown is not displayed."
        one = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
        one.click()
    select_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "currencyList")))
    select = Select(select_element)
    select.select_by_visible_text(text) # here text is "$ USD"
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however it worked to me nicely before because everytime you switch currency the page refreshes and then it is fine. however, I tried to run it with your code, I also updated the thread and added the new full code, and full output.

Comment: can you please join the discussion here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128720/automation

Comment: updated the code and working for me. please check. here level is the text "$ USD" (change to label if you want)

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the wanted select element (currency element) to appear:

```
select_visible_element = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'%s')]" %text)))
```

Alternatively you can click the dropdown, wait for the `select_visible_element` and `click()` it instead of select.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, 
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/AsosPriceCheckerWindows/currency.py", line 15, in set_currency
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'%s')]" % text)))
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 do you see the drop down opens before it waits for the currency element?